# Emacs quicker bookmark-jump?

Tags: emacs, elisp, bookmarks

I have most of my bookmarks prefixed by a letter in a way that
the first letter almost always uniquely determines the bookmark.
This way I can, for instance,
jump to my source folder (bookmarked as "s:  source") with <kbd>M-x bookmark-jump RET s RET</kbd>.
I have it on a shortcut, so it's actually <kbd>~ s RET</kbd>.

I'd like to get rid of <kbd>RET</kbd>  in the end,
i.e. get <kbd>M-x bookmark-quick-jump RET s</kbd>  or <kbd>~ s</kbd>
to do the aforementioned job.
I'd also like it to fall back to the default behavior: to show me all bookmarks
that start with the given letter, in case there's not just one variant.

So far, I've got:

```
(defun bookmark-do-quick-jump (str)
  (let ((completions (all-completions str bookmark-alist)))
    (bookmark-jump
     (if (eq 1 (length completions))
         (car completions)
       (completing-read "Jump to bookmark: " bookmark-alist nil t str)))))
```

There's still two hiccups:

Firstly, I need to jump into minibuffer somehow and stick in there this map (don't know how to do this):

```
(setq bookmark-quick-jump-map
      (let ((map (make-sparse-keymap)))
        (mapcar (lambda (key) 
                  (define-key map key 
                    (lambda()
                      (interactive)
                      (bookmark-do-quick-jump key))))
                (loop for c from ?a to ?z
                      collect (string c)))
        map))
```

Secondly, when I do a call

```
(bookmark-do-quick-jump "o")
```

It comes back with 3 variants (org-capture-last-stored, org-capture-last-stored-marker...).
I'm in minibuffer now, but I still need to press  <kbd>RET RET</kbd> 
to see these 3 variants. I'd like this to be done automatically.

I'd appreciate any responses that either directly answer my two sub-problems,
or an altogether different approach, as long as I can get the behavior and usability
that I described.

## UPD:

I've solved the second thing by switching from `completing-read` to `ido-completing-read`:

```
(defun bookmark-do-quick-jump (str)
  (let ((completions (all-completions str bookmark-alist)))
    (bookmark-jump
     (if (eq 1 (length completions))
         (car completions)
       (ido-completing-read "Jump to bookmark: " completions nil t str)))))
```

Btw, I forgot to mention that I use `bookmark+`. I'm not sure if jumping to dired
is supported by the default `bookmark-jump`.

Comment: This might be easier to achieve with a function that calls a keyboard macro. The only complication would be that one of the keys of the keyboard macro would have to be an argument of the function.

Comment: @abo-abo Would you please give the method used for creating a unique name for bookmarks and setting the shortcut as mentioned in the first lines of your question? Also, did you use auto-completing-read.el in the final solution? Thanks.

Comment: I make bookmark names by prefixing them with a unique character. I have only around 50, so the lower and upper case chars are enough.  See this for the implementation: http://oremacs.com/2015/01/06/rushing-headlong/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remap `self-insert-command` during the completing-read to trigger the auto-completion and auto-acceptance behaviour.

I originally used `(or (minibuffer-complete-and-exit) (minibuffer-completion-help))` which at first glance worked very nicely but, as noted in the comments, is less than ideal when one bookmark's name is the prefix of another, as it will immediately accept the shorter name, hence making the longer one inaccessible.

Calling `minibuffer-complete` and `minibuffer-completion-help` together breaks the completion functionality, however, so instead I've copied the relevant part of `minibuffer-complete-and-exit` to a new function. Using this resolves all of the earlier problems.

```el
(require 'bookmark)

(defvar bookmark-do-quick-jump-map (copy-keymap minibuffer-local-must-match-map)
  "Keymap for `bookmark-do-quick-jump'.

`minibuffer-local-must-match-map' is used by `completing-read' when its
REQUIRE-MATCH argument is t.

In `bookmark-do-quick-jump' we bind this modified copy to use in its place.")

(define-key bookmark-do-quick-jump-map
  [remap self-insert-command] 'my-self-insert-complete-and-exit)

(defun bookmark-do-quick-jump ()
  "Jump to specified bookmark with auto-completion and auto-acceptance."
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-maybe-load-default-file)
  (let ((minibuffer-local-must-match-map bookmark-do-quick-jump-map))
    (bookmark-jump
     (completing-read "Jump to bookmark: " bookmark-alist nil t))))

(defun my-self-insert-complete-and-exit (n)
  "Insert the character, then attempt to complete the current string,
automatically exiting when only one option remains, and displaying the
completion options otherwise."
  (interactive "p")
  (self-insert-command n)
  (my-minibuffer-complete)
  (let ((my-completions (completion-all-sorted-completions)))
    (if (and my-completions (eq 0 (cdr my-completions)))
        (exit-minibuffer)
      (minibuffer-completion-help))))

(defun my-minibuffer-complete ()
  "Copied from `minibuffer-complete-and-exit'."
  (interactive)
  (condition-case nil
      (completion--do-completion nil 'expect-exact)
    (error 1)))
```

---

**Edit:**

I took another stab at this using ido. It's a little unfortunate that you don't get the next 'important character' highlighted the way that you do with the regular minibuffer completion (as that was a nice indicator of what to type next), but this seems to work nicely in other respects.

```el
(require 'bookmark)
(require 'ido)

(defvar bookmark-ido-quick-jump-map (copy-keymap minibuffer-local-map)
  "Keymap for `bookmark-ido-quick-jump'.

Every time `ido-completing-read' is called it re-initializes
`ido-common-completion-map' and sets its parent to be `minibuffer-local-map'.

In `bookmark-ido-quick-jump' we provide this modified copy as a replacement
parent.")

(define-key bookmark-ido-quick-jump-map
  [remap self-insert-command] 'my-self-insert-and-ido-complete)

(defun bookmark-ido-quick-jump ()
  "Jump to selected bookmark, using auto-completion and auto-acceptance."
  (interactive)
  (bookmark-maybe-load-default-file)
  (let ((minibuffer-local-map bookmark-ido-quick-jump-map)
        (ido-enable-prefix t))
    (bookmark-jump
     (ido-completing-read "Jump to bookmark: " 
                          (loop for b in bookmark-alist collect (car b))))))

(defun my-self-insert-and-ido-complete (n)
  "Insert the character, then attempt to complete the current string,
automatically exiting when only one option remains."
  (interactive "p")
  (self-insert-command n)
  ;; ido uses buffer-local pre- and post-command hooks, so we need to
  ;; co-operate with those. We append our post-command function so that
  ;; it executes after ido has finished processing our self-insert.
  (add-hook 'post-command-hook
            'my-self-insert-and-ido-complete-post-command t t))

(defun my-self-insert-and-ido-complete-post-command ()
  (remove-hook 'post-command-hook
               'my-self-insert-and-ido-complete-post-command t)
  ;; Now that ido has finished its normal processing for the current
  ;; command, we simulate a subsequent `ido-complete' command.
  (ido-tidy) ;; pre-command-hook
  (ido-complete)
  (ido-exhibit)) ;; post-command-hook
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer, @phils.
A couple of things though:


1. I have to confirm with RET the unique bookmarks that start with
(1 2 d), but 0 and 8 work, for instance, as well as the other letters. Could this be a keymap problem?


2. `bookmark-do-quick-jump` with "o" matches
'(org-capture-last-stored org-capture-last-stored-marker org-refile-last-stored).
When I type "c", it instantly selects the first element, although the second one can still match.

Comment: Ah. Yes, if one bookmark name is a prefix of another, then it's also a valid completion on its own, so `minibuffer-complete-and-exit` exits as soon as it's completed to that point.

Comment: I'm not sure about your keymap issues, other than noting that single-character bookmark names do seem to cause a delay to tell me "[sole completion]" before taking me to the bookmark, whereas I do not observe this with longer names.

Comment: That pause appears to be due to the `expect-exact` argument to `completion--do-completion` (which `minibuffer-complete` does not pass, so it's on defaults). Force it to `t` and the message+delay doesn't happen. You could write some advice to deal to that, but I'm hoping there's a less messy solution to the issues.

Comment: I've added an `ido` version, which I think works better than the original version does (in its current state, at least).

Comment: I've tidied up the core functionality for this, and posted it on the wiki as [auto-completing-read.el](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/auto-completing-read.el)

Answer (score 2):

Here's another take:

```
(defun bookmark-do-quick-jump (str)
  (let ((completions (all-completions str bookmark-alist)))
    (if (null (cdr completions))
        (bookmark-jump (car completions))
      (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
          (lambda () (insert str)
                     (minibuffer-completion-help))
        (call-interactively 'bookmark-jump)))))
```

Or yet another (even more guaranteed untested):

```
(defadvice bookmark-jump (around quick-bookmarks activate)
  (minibuffer-with-setup-hook
      (lambda ()
        (add-hook 'post-self-insert-hook
                  (lambda ()
                    (let ((completions
                           (all-completions (minibuffer-contents)
                                            bookmark-alist)))
                      (if (cdr completions)
                          (minibuffer-completion-help)
                        (minibuffer-complete-and-exit))))
                  nil t))
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: I like the first one. Very concise.

Comment: There's a `post-self-insert-hook`? I didn't even think to look. *That* simplifies things.

Comment: @phils: it's new in Emacs-24.  But you can use `after-change-functions` in this case for similar results.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're doing  a lot of extra work.  Just use **[Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/Icicles)**.

- User option `icicle-incremental-completion` non-`nil` and non-`t` means show all matches as soon as you type input.
- Option `icicle-top-level-when-sole-completion-flag` non-`nil` means accept a solitary match without your needing to hit a key (e.g. <kbd>RET</kbd>).

Instead of customizing the options to have these values in general, you can just bind them to the values in your own command.

Comment: I tried icicles once and I din't like it.
It's too bloated. And not in a good `org-mode` kind of way,
but in a `gnus` king of way.