# Switch between frames by number or letter

Tags: emacs, elisp

I'd like to create a function that offers me numbered or lettered choices (`1, 2, 3`, or `a, b, c`) of available frames to switch to, instead of manually typing the name.  `Aspell` would be the closest example I can think of.

Could someone please share an example of how this might be done?  Lines 6 to 14 of the following function creates a list of all available frame names on the fly. Additional functions related to frame switching can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17823448/if-frame-named-xyz-exists-then-switch-to-that-frame)

```
(defun switch-frame (frame-to)
  (interactive  (list (read-string (format "From: (%s) => To: %s.  Select: "
    ;;  From:
    (frame-parameter nil 'name)
    ;;  To:
    (mapcar
      (lambda (frame) "print frame"
        (reduce 'concat
          (mapcar (lambda (s) (format "%s" s))
            (list "|" (frame-parameter frame 'name) "|" )
          )
        )
      )
    (frame-list) )
   )))) ;; end of interactive statement
  (setq frame-from (frame-parameter nil 'name))
  (let ((frames (frame-list)))
    (catch 'break
      (while frames
        (let ((frame (car frames)))
          (if (equal (frame-parameter frame 'name) frame-to)
              (throw 'break (select-frame-set-input-focus frame))
            (setq frames (cdr frames)))))) )
  (message "Switched -- From: \"%s\"  To: \"%s\"." frame-from frame-to) )
```

---

**EDIT** (November 13, 2014):  Here is a revised function using `ido-completing-read`:

```
(defun ido-switch-frame ()
(interactive)
  (when (not (minibufferp))
    (let* (
        (frames (frame-list))
        (frame-to (ido-completing-read "Select Frame:  "
          (mapcar (lambda (frame) (frame-parameter frame 'name)) frames))))
      (catch 'break
        (while frames
          (let ((frame (car frames)))
            (if (equal (frame-parameter frame 'name) frame-to)
              (throw 'break (select-frame-set-input-focus frame))
              (setq frames (cdr frames)))))))))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending upon the operating system, it may be necessary to use `(select-frame-set-input-focus chosen-frame)` instead of `select-frame` / `raise-frame` towards the end of the function.

```lisp
(defface frame-number-face
  '((t (:background "black" :foreground "red" )))
  "Face for `frame-number-face`."
  :group 'frame-fn)

(defface frame-name-face
  '((t ( :background "black" :foreground "ForestGreen")))
  "Face for `frame-name-face`."
  :group 'frame-fn)

(defun select-frame-number ()
"Select a frame by number -- a maximum of 9 frames are supported."
(interactive)
  (let* (
      choice
      chosen-frame
      (n 0)
      (frame-list (frame-list))
      (total-frames (safe-length frame-list))
      (frame-name-list
        (mapcar
          (lambda (frame) (cons frame (frame-parameter frame 'name)))
          frame-list))
      (frame-name-list-sorted
        (sort
          frame-name-list
          #'(lambda (x y) (string< (cdr x) (cdr y)))))
      (frame-number-list
        (mapcar
          (lambda (frame)
            (setq n (1+ n))
            (cons n (cdr frame)))
          frame-name-list-sorted))
      (pretty-list
        (mapconcat 'identity
          (mapcar
            (lambda (x) (concat
              "["
              (propertize (format "%s" (car x)) 'face 'frame-number-face)
              "] "
              (propertize (format "%s" (cdr x)) 'face 'frame-name-face)))
            frame-number-list)
          " | "))  )
    (message "%s" pretty-list)
    (setq choice (read-char-exclusive))
    (cond
      ((eq choice ?1)
        (setq choice 1))
      ((eq choice ?2)
        (setq choice 2))
      ((eq choice ?3)
        (setq choice 3))
      ((eq choice ?4)
        (setq choice 4))
      ((eq choice ?5)
        (setq choice 5))
      ((eq choice ?6)
        (setq choice 6))
      ((eq choice ?7)
        (setq choice 7))
      ((eq choice ?8)
        (setq choice 8))
      ((eq choice ?9)
        (setq choice 9))
      (t
        (setq choice 10)))
    (setq chosen-frame (car (nth (1- choice) frame-name-list-sorted)))
    (when (> choice total-frames)
      (let* (
          (debug-on-quit nil)
          (quit-message
            (format "You must select a number between 1 and %s." total-frames)))
        (signal 'quit `(,quit-message ))))
    (select-frame chosen-frame)
    (raise-frame chosen-frame)
    chosen-frame))
```

---

[image: Example]

Answer (score 2):

I see what you're trying to do. Here's how I've solved this problem:

### Part 1

The files that you use every day should be bookmarked.
The reason is that you loose focus when you're reading any sort of menu,
even as short as you describe. After some time with bookmarks,
it becomes like touch-typing: you select the buffer without thinking about it.

You can check out this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496021/emacs-quicker-bookmark-jump)
to see my system.
I've got about 20 important files and buffers bookmarked and reachable
in two keystrokes, e.g. <kbd>μ k</kbd> for `keys.el` and <kbd>μ h</kbd> for `hooks.el`.
A nice bonus is that `bookmark-bmenu-list` shows all this stuff, so I can

1. add/remove bookmarks easily
2. rename bookmarks (renaming changes binding)
3. it's clickable with mouse (sometimes useful)

`bookmark+` allows function bookmarks, so I've got `org-agenda` on <kbd>μ a</kbd>
and `magit` on <kbd>μ m</kbd>.
And of course the `dired` bookmarks: source is on <kbd>μ s</kbd> and
org-files are on <kbd>μ g</kbd>.

### Part 2

For the files that can't be bookmarked, I'm using:

```
(ido-mode)
(setq ido-enable-flex-matching t)
(global-set-key "η" 'ido-switch-buffer)
```

This is fast as well: you need one keystroke to call `ido-switch-buffer`
and around 2-3 letters to find the buffer you need, and `RET` to select.

I've also recently added this hack:

```
(add-hook 'ido-setup-hook
          (lambda()
            (define-key ido-buffer-completion-map "η" 'ido-next-match)))
```

With this you can use the same key to call `ido-switch-buffer` and cycle the selection.

### Part 3

The actual function with lettered choices has been on my todo list for a while
now. I'll post back here when I get around to implementing it,
or maybe just copy the solution from a different answer:)

Comment: Yes, that is essentially the ultimate goal -- similar to ido switching of buffers, but for frames also -- with auto-generated lists of available choices.  Thank you for sharing your system.

Answer (score 1):

1. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18159007/2448650) describes **[Icicles](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles)** command `icicle-select-frame`, which lets you choose frames by name using completion.
2. There is also **Icicles** command `icicle-other-window-or-frame` (`C-x o`), which combines commands `icicle-select-frame`, `other-frame`, and `other-window`.  It lets you select a window or a frame, by its name or by order.

   - With no prefix arg or a non-zero numeric prefix arg:
     If the selected frame has multiple windows then this is
     `other-window`.  Otherwise, it is `other-frame`.
   - With a zero prefix arg (e.g. `C-0`):
     If the selected frame has multiple windows then this is
     `icicle-select-window` with windows in the frame as candidates.
     Otherwise (single-window frame), this is `icicle-select-frame`.
   - With plain `C-u`:
     If the selected frame has multiple windows then this is
     `icicle-select-window` with windows from all visible frames as
     candidates.  Otherwise, this is `icicle-select-frame`.

Comment: Thank you for the post -- I'll check it out in the next few days -- greatly appreciated!