# Special Emacs setup for a single file: Run lisp code at startup from command line

Tags: bash, emacs, elisp, command-line-arguments

Suppose I have I file `A.txt`, which I often edit and also, into which I often insert the text "Test". It would then be nice if I could just press e.g. the F5 key to insert the text "Test" into the buffer. However, when I edit any other file I do not want the F5 key to be bound in this way.

It would then be nice if I could avoid messing up my `.emacs` init file with special code. Hence, consider defining a new file `start.el` located in the same directory as `A.txt`. The contents of `start.el` could be:

```
(defun insert-test-text ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "Test"))
(global-set-key '[f5]  'insert-test-text)
```

Then I write a `bash` script `editA` for editing the file `A.txt` in Emacs, e.g.

```
#! /bin/bash

emacs --run-code-on-init start.el A.txt &
```

The command line option `run-code-on-init` is unfortunately not a valid option.. Is there any good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could get the effect you want by doing

```
emacs -l start.el a.txt
```

out of the box. According to the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/emacs), that should start up `emacs` editing `a.txt`, with the `lisp` code in `start.el` loaded.

Does that work, or is there a reason the simple solution doesn't work for your use case?

Comment: Perfect! Just what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

Here's my view of the solution:

```
(defun insert-test-text ()
  (interactive)
  (insert "test"))

(add-hook 
 'text-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (if (string= (file-name-nondirectory (buffer-file-name))
                "A.txt")
       (local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'insert-test-text))))
```

This will define the shortcut only for files named `A.txt`.
You should tweak the code to your needs, of course.

Also, don't forget to bookmark the file if you edit it a lot.
I've got a very quick setup (around two key chords) for ~20 files/directories.
that I edit a lot. The setup is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17496021/emacs-quicker-bookmark-jump).

### UPD

If you want the binding for single file, just drop `file-name-nondirectory` like so:

```
(add-hook 
 'text-mode-hook
 (lambda ()
   (if (string= (buffer-file-name)
                "~/A.txt")
       (local-set-key (kbd "<f5>") 'insert-test-text))))
```

And here's what I do to keep my config manageable - in `~/.emacs`:

```
(defvar dropbox.d "~/Dropbox/")
(defvar emacs.d (concat dropbox.d "source/site-lisp/"))
(add-to-list 'load-path emacs.d)
(defun add-subdirs-to-load-path (dir)
    (let ((default-directory dir))
      (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)))
(add-subdirs-to-load-path emacs.d)
(load "init")
;; you can put the code in "source/site-lisp/feature1.el"
(load "feature1")
```

That's about the whole content of my `~/.emacs` - the rest of the config is
it the respective files in `site-lisp` dir.
You can comment out the `(load "feature1")` to turn it off temporarily.

Comment: Thank you! Now, I may have many files called `A.txt` (in different directories).. But the setup should only be valid for one of these. Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: Also it would be nice if I could separate the code from the `.emacs` file, as I mentioned..

Comment: Thanks for the update.. It seems to me that I also can get the desired effect using the simpler `-l` switch in `Inaimathi` answer.. Thanks anyway.